# Help with script reading numbers from a file and determining if they are even or odd numbers

Tags: shell, shell-script, test, arithmetic

So I want my script to test for the existence of a file which I already populated with numbers. It does that, but after it does that I want it to run a while look checking to see if the numbers in the file are either odd or even as it checks each number on each line. For all I know my script structure is bad, but the code I have below does not produce a desired result.

```
exist=rnddata.txt
if [ -f $exist ]; then
 echo "file exist processing"
else
 echo "file does not exist"
exit1
fi
while read exist
do
if [ $((exist % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then
 echo "even"
else
echo "odd"
fi
done
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
while read number
do
    if [ $((number % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then 
        echo even
    else    
        echo odd 
    fi      
done < "$exist"
```

`read` reads into variables on it's command line.  So you have to feed the file data into the loop so `read` can get it.  Here we do that with the `< "$exist"` after the `done` of the `while` loop.

The `read` command doesn't have a manpage because it's a shell builtin.  To see how it works, type `man sh` (hint, search for `readonly` because that's a lot easier to find.)

Answer (score 0):

for the most part you don't have to worry about stuff like:

```
if    [ -e "$file" ]
then  echo exists
else  echo not exists
fi
```

when people do that kind of stuff they're really just spinning their wheels. it also can be problematic in that there's little to connect between the behavior and output format of one script versus another. and it's all wasted effort anyway because:

```
sh -c 'exec <not_exist; echo can i\?' my_zero
```

---

```
my_zero: 1: my_zero: cannot open not_exist: No such file
```

a scripted POSIX shell dies with cause written to stderr when a special shell-builtin is the object of any failed shell-redirection. the special builtins are:

```
: continue break exec set . shift unset
times trap exit export readonly eval return
```

their special status can be demoted by calling them via `command`:

```
sh -c 'command exec <not_exist; echo can i\?' my_zero
```

---

```
my_zero: 1: my_zero: cannot open not_exist: No such file
can i?
```

and so the most straight-forward and effective strategy to dealing robustly with read/write files is to put the file directly on the file-descriptor with which you mean to interact, and the let the shell handle any/all error output as necessary. it will just happen if it should and if you write your scripts with an eye for allowing actions to speak for themselves.

```
sh -c '
    cat_fname()
        for   f
        do    exec   <"$f"
              printf "\n%-5s%-$((${#f}+2))s%s\n" === "$f" ===
              cat
        done
    cat_fname a[1-9]/a[1-9].txt not_exist /dev/fd/0'
```

---

```
===  a1/a1.txt  ===
1 1 1 11 1 1 1 1

===  a2/a2.txt  ===
2 2 2 12 2 2 2 2

===  a3/a3.txt  ===
3 3 3 13 3 3 3 3

===  a4/a4.txt  ===
4 4 4 14 4 4 4 4

===  a5/a5.txt  ===
5 5 5 15 5 5 5 5

===  a6/a6.txt  ===
6 6 6 16 6 6 6 6

===  a7/a7.txt  ===
7 7 7 17 7 7 7 7

===  a8/a8.txt  ===
8 8 8 18 8 8 8 8

===  a9/a9.txt  ===
9 9 9 19 9 9 9 9
sh: 4: cannot open not_exist: No such file
```